# Does Dell Openmanage software require a reboot to install?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell, dell-poweredge, dell-openmanage

I need to install Openmanage to get the system temperatures and would ideally like to do it now instead of waiting until the weekend. Can someone tell me if I can do this without interrupting the server's operation or is there another way to monitor temps? System is a PowerEdge 2950, Windows Server 2003 R2, MSSQL 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished putting it on a batch of 2003, 2003 R2, 2008, and 2008 R2 machines and none required a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to install some specific driver, you should only start DSM SA services manually after installation.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, although I have a sneaking suspicion this particular server will require the drivers as it's a fairly vanilla install. Thanks anyhoo.